# pass parameters to SSRS report filter dropdown using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to pass parameters to SSRS report filter dropdown usingasp.net but I was unable to sent the value to dropdown.

Please help for this.
[Want to pass this two value using C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpOY2.png)

I want to pass or set this this two parameter value using C#

Comment: Hi tanmay can you please explain in details and with some screenshots so people can easily understand you and answer you properly.

Comment: You want to cascade the params? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: alredy add screen shot

Comment: but I want to do it through C#

Comment: ok , here's the C# version, you need to get and pass the  values through C#, Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to send value to dropdown, 
You have to make cascading dropdowns in the asp.net  C# first, And get the values from there, and then pass to report parameter as:

```
//get 'selected value' or 'text' as per your need
var market = ddMarket.SelectedItem.Text; 
var customer = ddCustomer.SelectedItem.Text; 
List<ReportParameter> params = new List<ReportParameter>();
reportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("rptParamMarket", market));
reportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("rptParamCust", customer));
ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(params);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Make sure `"rptParamMarket"` and `"rptParamCust"` matches that of the names of parameters in report.

That, in essence, means your report will be displayed based on the values you pass to it from the code behind.

Comment: not working still unable to select value from report dropdown
cascading drop down is in repot it self so need to select value from these drop  down not from asp.net

Comment: report drop down already contain value so how I can set these value with specific index

Comment: its not an issue, report dropdown is basically to pass value to parameters, so you just have to _PASS_ those values, and you can pass it to them from anywhere, from ASP.NET application, or [via report URL..](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/) etc..
Better you check your query in the dataset, and check the report parameters to get it to know clearly..

Comment: thnx this what I am searching pl upvote my question so I can up vote your ans

Comment: @TTN of course, we have to help each other by promoting good questions and answers.!